# Select records from two tables based on the MAX of one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I'm trying to get only one row to display for each volume and drawing_num based on the MAX of a date field. I'm posting my query below along with the results I'm getting plus what the results I'm intending to get. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT
    cc_qaqc_drawings.volume,
    cc_qaqc_drawings.drawing_num,
    cc_qaqc_drawings.drawing_name,
    MAX(cc_qaqc_drawings_detail.rev_date) AS revdate,
    cc_qaqc_drawings_detail.rev_desc,
    cc_qaqc_drawings_detail.rev_type,
    da.cc_qaqc_drawings.id
FROM da.cc_qaqc_drawings
LEFT JOIN da.cc_qaqc_drawings_detail 
  ON da.cc_qaqc_drawings.id = da.cc_qaqc_drawings_detail.draw_id
WHERE cc_qaqc_drawings.jobnumber = '2099'
GROUP BY
    cc_qaqc_drawings.volume,
    cc_qaqc_drawings.drawing_num,
    cc_qaqc_drawings.drawing_name,
    da.cc_qaqc_drawings.id,
    cc_qaqc_drawings_detail.rev_desc,
    cc_qaqc_drawings_detail.rev_type
ORDER BY
    cc_qaqc_drawings.volume,
    cc_qaqc_drawings.drawing_num,
    MAX(cc_qaqc_drawings_detail.rev_date) DESC;
```

Below are the results I'm getting with the query above.

| Volume | DrawNum | DrawName | RevDate | RevDesc | RevType | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1001 | Windows | 21-MAR-23 | Glass | RFDC | 2250 |
| 1 | A1001 | Windows | 20-MAR-23 | Glass | RFDC | 2250 |
| 1 | A1001 | Windows | 19-MAR-23 | Glass | ASI | 2250 |
| 1 | A1001 | Windows | 18-MAR-23 | Glass | RFI | 2250 |
| 1 | A4400 | Frames | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2244 |
| 1 | A6100 | Schedule | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2245 |
| 9 | A1099 | Drawings | 18-MAR-23 | Classes | RFI | 2261 |
| 9 | A1099 | Drawings | 17-MAR-23 | Classes | RFDC | 2261 |

Below are the results I would like to get.

| Volume | DrawNum | DrawName | RevDate | RevDesc | RevType | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1001 | Windows | 21-MAR-23 | Glass | RFDC | 2250 |
| 1 | A4400 | Frames | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2244 |
| 1 | A6100 | Schedule | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2245 |
| 9 | A1099 | Drawings | 18-MAR-23 | Classes | RFI | 2261 |

Comment: 1) Please fix your query which currently doesn't even have a `select` keyword, 2) please show sample data, 3) consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/123481/1024832

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it posted already. I'm fixing it now.

Comment: @Marc I've fixed it now. I guess I must have pressed the post button on accident.

Comment: This question is pretty much answered at the link I posted in my first comment.

Comment: Please prepend each column with the table name it belongs to. We can't really guess where each one belongs to.

Comment: @TheImpaler done. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want. Then filtering is trivial.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT
    d.volume,
    d.drawing_num,
    d.drawing_name,
    t.rev_date,
    t.rev_desc,
    t.rev_type,
    d.id,
    row_number() over(partition by d.volume, d.drawing_num 
                      order by t.rev_date desc) as rn
  FROM da.cc_qaqc_drawings d
  LEFT JOIN da.cc_qaqc_drawings_detail t ON d.id = t.draw_id
  WHERE d.jobnumber = '2099'
) x
where rn = 1
```